# unable to receive the state in react component from redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to display the redux state into my react component, but it comes undefined.
I am unable to understand where am I doing the mistake. 
I am learning redux by trying a coding on my own by going through the redux documentation.

Main React component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from './components/Counter';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
          <h1>COUNTER APPlICATION</h1>
          <Counter />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

React Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addNumber} from '../redux/actions/addAction';
import {substractNumber} from '../redux/actions/substractAction';

export class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Value:{this.props.value}</h1>
        <h1>Add Only Value:{this.props.addOnly}</h1>
        <button onClick = {() => this.props.addNumber}>+</button>
        <button onClick = {() => this.props.substractNumber}>-</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  value: state.value
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addNumber, substractNumber})(Counter);
```

addReducer

```
import {ADDITION} from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  value: 50
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case ADDITION:
      return{
        value: state.value + 2
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

substractReducer

```
import {SUBSTRACTION} from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  value: 50
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SUBSTRACTION:
      return {
        value: state.value - 2
      }
      default:
        return state
  }
}
```

rootReducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import addReducer from './addReducer';
import substractReducer from './substractReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  add: addReducer,
  substract: substractReducer
})
```

store

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/rootReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

action type

```
export const ADDITION = 'ADDITION';
export const SUBSTRACTION = 'SUBSTRACTION';
```

addAction

```
import {ADDITION} from './actionTypes';
export const addNumber = () => (dispatch) => {
  return dispatch({
    type: ADDITION,
    payload: 2
  })
}
```

substractAction

```
import {SUBSTRACTION} from './actionTypes';

export const substractNumber = () => (dispatch) => {
  return dispatch({
    type: SUBSTRACTION,
    payload: 2
  })
}
```

Comment: *Where* are you getting the `undefined` value?

Comment: when calling it within the counter component

Comment: Are you using two reducers to try and modify the same `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `combineReducers` like this:

```
export default combineReducers({
  add: addReducer,
  substract: substractReducer
})
```

Your state tree will look like:

```
{
    add: {
        value: 0
    },
    subtract: {
        value: 0
    }
}
```

So you should only have a single reducer in order to reduce over the same value.

Comment: i understood now, i was getting confused

Answer (score 2):

You are doing wrong.

1. you state is just counter value, so don't split into two reducers. You only need two case statement, one for `ADD`, one for `SUBTRACT`.
2. Don't use `combineReducer` and it you want, use one key like `counter` for counter reducer
3. in mapStateToProp, get value like `state.counter.value` where `counter` is name of key you used in `combineReducer({ counter: counterReducer })`
4. Your button actions/onclick is wrong

```js
import {ADDITION, SUBTRACTION} from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  value: 50
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type){
    case ADDITION:
      return 
        value: state.value + 2
      }
      
   case SUBTRACTION:
      return{
        value: state.value + 2
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

///// no need to regester 2 reducer, just add one above like this

export default combineReducers({
  counter: counterReducer
});

/// In Counter component , mapStateToProp
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  value: state.counter.value
});

// Just pass redux actions to onClick in button like this
<button onClick = {this.props.addNumber}>+</button>
<button onClick = {this.props.substractNumber}>-</button>
```

Comment: const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  value: state.value
}); why are we adding state.counter.value

Comment: No, if you are using `combineReducers`, you need the name of reducer from which you want to access the value.

Comment: @ShefaliUpadhyay I updated the answer. you just need to pass the action as onClick prop